# Getting error white using ngx-bootstrap-modal in production mode angular 2

Tags: angular

Cannot resolve all parameters for 'l'(?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or have valid type annotations and that 'l' is decorated with Injectable.
Below is my code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ItemModalComponent } from './item-modal/item-modal.component';
import { BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/modal-options.class';
import { BsModalService } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal/bs-modal.service';


@Component({
selector: 'app-items',
templateUrl: 'items.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./items.component.scss']
})

export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {


bsModalRef: BsModalRef;
constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}



openItemModal() {
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ItemModalComponent, {class: 
    'modal-lg'});
    console.log(this.bsModalRef);
    this.bsModalRef.content.title = 'New Item';
  }

ngOnInit() { }
}
```

Comment: is the error coming while doing aot build ?

Comment: no it builds successfully, plus its works in development mode

Comment: tried using @Inject decorator for BsModalService still not working

Answer (score 0):

Which angular version you are using? Delete existing node module and install new one. Might be this will help you